# Show/hide div based on select and checkboxes when page loads and on change

Tags: jquery

I have divs which are displayed when a select box is changed. Inside those divs are checkboxes which, when checked, show  child divs. I have it working so that the divs are shown/hidden on change of select and subsequent child divs are shown/hidden when checked/unchecked.

```
// Show/Hide checkbox divs using select
$('#set').change(function(){
    $('.checkboxes').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});

// Show/Hide sub questions using checkboxes
$('div.checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + this.id + '-qs').toggle( this.checked ); 
});
```

How can I make it so that the first level div is displayed when an option element already has the selected attribute?

```
<option value="set1" selected>One</option>
```

And the same for the checkboxes when they have the checked attribute?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="set1-questions1" id="set1-questions1" checked>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/paulyabsley/GKJ8U/)

i.e. on the above demo  should show and inside of that  should show.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger `change()` event on page load:

```
// Show/Hide checkbox divs using select
$('#set').change(function(){
    $('.checkboxes').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
}).change(); // or .trigger('change');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKJ8U/12/)**